# Node.js throws the below "events.js:72 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' even"

Tags: node.js

I am running one .js script and new to the node.js, I am getting below errors:

> 2014-08-12 23:24:20.986 UTC - Server running at 10.11.6.249:9090
>
> events.js:72
>           throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>                 ^ Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL
>
> ```
> at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
>
> at Server._listen2 (net.js:1023:19)
>
> at listen (net.js:1064:10)
>
> at net.js:1146:9
>
> at dns.js:72:18
>
> at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
>
> at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:499:11)
>
> at startup (node.js:119:16)
>
> at node.js:906:3
> ```

Not sure why these errors are I have closed the port 8000 and re-launch app as well, still facing the same issue.

Comment: try changing the port number..

Answer (score 1):

It is not a problem of port (through I don't understand 8000 or 9090) it is a problem of IP address. Either it was changed and is hardcoded, or IP conflict in network. Run it with 127.0.0.1